# Top 80% Percent of Sales

Tags: python

My goal is to filter only the top 80% of products that makeup of sales

I have a Total of 100 products and the total of sales was 15000, so to find out what is the percent of the product of sales I'm doing this

```
product_dict = {}
for product in products:
    percent_from_sale = product.quantity / total_quantity * 100
    product_dict[product] = percent_from_sale
```

so after this I have dict with the key product and values is the percent of this product sale, but how can I filter only top 80%?

Comment: Top 80% of products, or those products that make up 80% of sales?

Comment: @schwobaseggl yea you are right

Comment: How can I be right asking a question =)

Comment: @AlexanderLekontsev I edited my question after hi asked me

Comment: Is numpy or pandas allowed? Both could reduce the required LOC and increase the performance substantially.

Comment: @JE_Muc it is, just I have no experience with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define [generator function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators) which will *yield* elements until cumulative sum reach some limit:

```py
def iter_until(src, limit, key):
    cumulative_sum = 0
    for element in src:
        yield element
        cumulative_sum += key(element)
        if cumulative_sum >= limit:
            break
```

Let's generate input similar to your:

```py
from collections import namedtuple
from random import shuffle

product = namedtuple("product", "name quantity")
total_quantity = 15000
products = [product(f"product{i}", total_quantity // (2 ** i)) for i in range(1, 101)]
shuffle(products)
```

Now you can iterate over generator function. You can create *list* of top 80% of sales:

```py
sorted_products = sorted(products, key=lambda x: x.quantity, reverse=True)
top_80_percent = list(iter_until(sorted_products, total_quantity * 0.8, lambda x: x.quantity))
```

You can create dict *(what you're trying to do in code form question)*:

```
sorted_products = sorted(products, key=lambda x: x.quantity, reverse=True)
top_80_percent = {p.name: p.quantity for p in iter_until(sorted_products, total_quantity * 0.8, lambda x: x.quantity)}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can convert the `product_dict{product:sales}` to `sales_list[(sales, product)]`

```
sales_list=[(v,k) for k,v in product_dict.items()]
```

The sort the sales_list by sales in reverse (high to low)

```
sales_list.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x:x[0])
```

Then iterate on it computing the cumulative sum till it is *less than 80*

```
cumulative_sale = 0
top_80_products = {}
for sale, product in sales_list:
    top_80_products[product] = sale
    cumulative_sale += sale
    if cumulative_sale >= 80:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer by @lllrnr101, but with a slight variation on sorting.

Use can get a list of sorted tuples `(product, percent)` by the second argument (percent) using `operator.itemgetter` function.
Then iterate over the pairs until 80% of the cumulative sales is reached.

```
import operator

product_dict = {
    product: percent
    for product in products
}

sorted_items = sorted(
    product_dict.items(),
    key=operator.itemgetter(1),
    reverse=True,
)

cumulative = 0
top_80_sales = {}
for product, percent in sorted_items:
    if cumulative < 0.8:
        top_80_sales[product] = percent
        cumulative += percent
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use pandas or numpy, you can reduce the required LOC substantially and increase the performance (especially for a large number of products).

To start with pandas, first import it and make a dataframe out of your data (sample data creation taken from Olvin Roght):

```
from collections import namedtuple
from random import shuffle

import pandas as pd

# create sample data
product = namedtuple("product", "name quantity")
total_quantity = 15000
products = [product(f"product{i}", total_quantity // (2 ** i)) for i in range(1, 101)]
shuffle(products)

# make into dataframe
prods = pd.DataFrame(products)
```

Now sort the dataframe by the quantity:

```
prods_sort = prods.sort_values(by='quantity', ascending=False)
```

And get the top 80% of the products:

```
top_products = prods_sort[
    ~prods_sort.loc[:, 'quantity'].cumsum().ge(
        prods_sort.loc[:, 'quantity'].sum() * .8
    ).shift(1, fill_value=False)

print(top_products)

# Out:
        name  quantity
40  product1      7500
94  product2      3750
65  product3      1875
```

what I am doing here:

- get the cumulative sum of the quantity
- check where the cumulative sum is greater/equal (`.ge(...)`) than 80% of the total sum, yields a boolean array
- shift this by 1 (`.shift(1, fill_value=False)`) to also include the first value, which is greater/equal than 80% of the sum and fill with `False` (else the first value will be filled with `np.nan`)
- index the sorted products with this boolean array to get the products which make up for 80% of the total quantity